# VBA calling stored procedure ignores IF statement

Tags: sql, vba

We are trying to tweak some VBA code in an Access ADP that pulls data from a stored procedure. The stored procedure is quite long, but at the end, uses some if statements to determine what info to return. Pretty basic. We have tried the statements two ways:

```
IF (@InadDrugId = 7)
BEGIN
    IF (@Table = 1)
    BEGIN
        ... some code section 1
    END
    IF (@Table = 2)
    BEGIN
        ... some code section 2
    END
END
```

and also:

```
IF (@InadDrugId = 7 AND @Table = 1)
    BEGIN
        ... some code section 1
    END
IF (@InadDrugId = 7 AND @Table = 2)
    BEGIN
        ... some code section 2
    END
```

The section '... some code section 1' always fires even if we have @Table = 2. Any thoughts why?

I can do this in SSMS:

```
EXEC dbo.procPathINADforAnnualFDAreportTdrNdr '1/1/2011','12/31/2011',2011,2,1
EXEC dbo.procPathINADforAnnualFDAreportTdrNdr '1/1/2011','12/31/2011',2011,7,2
EXEC dbo.procPathINADforAnnualFDAreportTdrNdr '1/1/2011','12/31/2011',2011,26,1
```

And get 3 different results, however, when VBA does it, it always gives the same results, and I know that it is passing the correct parameters.

Comment: This is Acess 2007. When we fire the stored proc in SSMS it works as expected.

Comment: Some idea about the datatypes of the variables and the intended function of the code would be helpful.  If you have version specific issues, it is likely an inconsistency in the way the data type is handled.

Comment: If code section 1 is always firing then `@Table` must be 1. You should look for bugs in the Access program. It must be passing the wrong value for `@Table` or you are interpreting the results wrong.

Comment: Nope, `@Table` IS 2, but still hits 1. A little more info, the returned column headers are different depending on the IF statement.  
AGAIN, it works as expected when you paste the sql string into SSMS from VBA, but if you let VBA call it it always does the first select statement, regardless of parameters.  
`IF @Table = 1  
BEGIN  
SELECT PaStateFishHatchery AS SFH, TotNumTrtmts AS TotTrtmts  
...  
END  
IF @Table = 2  
BEGIN  
SELECT PaStateFishHatchery AS SFH, PFBCTreatmentID AS TrtmtID  
...  
END`

Comment: Another thing we found, originally this stored proc had CREATE #tempTable statements in it. VBA broke trying to run it, even though the proc ran fine in SSMS. We changed the proc to not use #tempTables. (Some @tableVariables still there.)

Comment: Can you show us your VBA code? Also, what are the parameter types?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just missing the THEN?

The syntax for the IF-THEN-ELSE statement is:

```
If condition_1 Then
   result_1
ElseIf condition_2 Then
  result_2
...
ElseIf condition_n Then
   result_n
Else
  result_else
End If
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure procPathINADforAnnualFDAreportTdrNdr, Line 1325 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'. 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure procPathINADforAnnualFDAreportTdrNdr, Line 1329 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'. 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure procPathINADforAnnualFDAreportTdrNdr, Line 1342 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question was not very specific about how exactly is the SP being used in ADP, this is going to be a wild guess... Please take a look at this Q&A:

[SQL Server 2005: “Protecting” stored procedures from FMTONLY mode used by MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303152/sql-server-2005-protecting-stored-procedures-from-fmtonly-mode-used-by-ms-acc)

Is it possible that you have exactly a case when Access is calling your SP in FMTONLY mode? Because that's exactly when all IFs "magically" cease to work unless you circumvent FMTONLY explicitly.